# react + socket.io socket.on event is not updating state properly

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, state

here's a bit of code. My problem is im using exact same setMessage when im sending message and it updates my array properly, however when receiving message from server ( socket.on('message')) the state doesnt update properly - all my previous messages disappear from array only the one ive received updates. ( sometimes when ive got array of 5 messages it leaves 2 and deletes 3) very strange behaviour while updating the state. Anybody could tell me what's wrong with this line: `setMessages([...messages, {name: nick, value: value}])`  It seems like it clears my state when socket.on is called? I'm kinda lost :D

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!mainScreen) {
      const socket = io("http://localhost:3001/");
      setClient(socket);
      socket.on("joined_room", (data) => {
        setCurrentRoom(data.room_name);
        console.log(data.room_name);
      });

      socket.on("message", (data) => {
        setMessages([...messages, {name: nick, value: value}])
      });
      return ()=>{
        socket.disconnect();
      }
    }
  }, [mainScreen]);
```

Here's my send message function that updates my local state properly

```
const sendMessage = (message, nick) => {
    setMessages([...messages, { name: nick, value: message }]);
    client.emit("message", { room: currentRoom, value: message, nick: nick });
  };
```

Comment: I don't know `socket.io` at all, but it could be cos it makes a snapshot of the `.on` function when the effect runs, which at the start is when the messages array is empty. For state changes that rely on previous state, using a function argument is usually safest, so that it properly preserves the previous state snapshot. So try `setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, {name: nick, value: value}])`, see if that preserves the current messages

Comment: It worked, thanks man, need to dive deeper to spnapshoting or whatever react is doin behind the curtains :) appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, this would fix that:

```
  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    setMessages(messages => [...messages, {name: nick, value: value}]);
  });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why this works? any documentation resource about putting a function inside the setter?